# when i have to calculate mape rmse before or after inverse_transform

Tags: python, predictive-models, mape, gru

hello i want to know when i have to calculate mape rmse  before this code
`predictions1 =scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)`or after it. because the result is different in two propositionsthat's it what i m doing :`predictions = gru_model.predict(X_test)print("Mean Absolute Error - mape : " + str(mape...(y_test, predictions)))`
MAPE:  0.06919089575979946
mse et rmse for train and test
Train Score: 0.0003 MSE (0.0167 RMSE)
Validatin Score: 0.0029 MSE (0.0536 RMSE)

Comment: You selectively show a couple lines before the error is raised. This doesn't provide enough information to figure out what went wrong. And please take a look at the [editing guidelines](https://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to learn how to format code. Then fix your question.

Comment: okey i will fix it